# php function with Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Tags: php

The PHP function below is producing this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', on this line that contens this code:`( $className, new $this->registerService( $service ) );`

Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
function lazyCreateSingletonServiceByClassName($className) {
    $service = $this->createContextAwareObjectOfClass( $className );

    if (method_exists( $service, 'init' )) {
        $service->init(  );
    }

    SingletonServiceProvider;
    ( $className, new $this->registerService( $service ) );


}
```

tanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell exactly what's going on here but i *think* that

```
SingletonServiceProvider;
( $className, new $this->registerService( $service ) );
```

should be

```
SingletonServiceProvider( $className, new $this->registerService( $service ) );
```

Comment: Possibly even `new SingletonServiceProvider( $className, $this->registerService( $service ) );` - it's still hard to figure out what this line should do but it is seriously mixed up.