# php function with Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$'

Tags: php

The PHP function below is producing this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$', on this line that contens this code:`$obj = new (  );`

Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
function createContextAwareObjectOfClass($className) {
    $className;
    $obj = new (  );
    IApplicationContextAware;

    if (!( $obj instanceof null )) {
        Exception;
        throw new ( '' . 'Non-context aware class "' . $className . '" passed to createContextAwareObjectOfClass' );
    }

    $obj->setAppContext( $this );
    return $obj;
}
```

Comment: [Quit putting your code in a blender!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594988/php-function-with-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think*

```
$obj = new (  );
IApplicationContextAware;
```

should be

```
$obj = new IApplicationContextAware();
```